# How to validate JSON input using Golang?

Tags: json, validation, go, beego

I'm using Beego framework to build a web application in Go. I have to validate the incoming JSON in an API request.

I can unmarshal the JSON into a struct which works fine, but I want to validate the data as well. For example, if the type doesn't match with the type in struct json.Unmarshal will reutrn an error on the first occurence. I want to validate and get all the errors at once for JSON.

I've tried `https://github.com/thedevsaddam/govalidator` but the package needs a reference to request object which is not available in the controller of Beego. There are other validators which can validate a struct but i want the json validation as well.

**EDIT:**

A reference to the request object in beego can be found from the controller's context object as:

```
func (this *MainController) Post() {
    fmt.Println(this.Ctx.Request)
}
```

**But** the problem remains same with json unmarshal. If there's any slight mismatch in the type, json.unmarshal will immediately panic. I want to be able to validate the type as well.

Comment: This isn't supported by the standard library, so it seems you're asking for a 3rd party lib? That is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Either a 3rd party library or any solution is welcomed.

Comment: [`json.Decoder.Token()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Token) might help, but it will require quite a bit of code.

Answer (score 13):

Since Golang v1.9 `json.Valid([]byte)` has been a valid method available from the "encoding/json" package.

Reference:
https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Valid

Answer (score 6):

We've used [go-playground/validator.v8](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8) for a similar purpose. You can define the data validations with the tags that come out of the box (basic stuff like equality, min/max and even has somthing of an expression lang). On top of that you can add your custom validations. It's all in the docs, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method `checkValid` (in `encoding/json` package) which can do that. This method, however, is not exposed. So, you can use `Unmarshal` (in same package) to check if `JSON` is valid.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this today so I will share my solution. I created a function using unmarshal that returns true or false based on whether the text returns valid json:

```
// isJSON checks that the string value of the field can unmarshall into valid json
func isJSON(s string) bool {
    var j map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &j); err != nil {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Then I used that logic with the validator package to make and register a custom validation tag that I can use in any struct to validate that a field contains json. You can use [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/O0Npboe4_w9) to check the full solution and experiment:

```
// isJSON checks that the string value of the field can unmarshall into valid json
func isJSON(fl validator.FieldLevel) bool {
    var j map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(fl.Field().String()), &j); err != nil {
        return false
    }
    return true
}

// register the function with json tag:
validate.RegisterValidation("json", isJSON)
```

Comment: Thanks this helped. I've updated `isJson` to return `error`:

```
func isJSON(s string) error {
 var j map[string]interface{}
 return json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &j)
}
```